# is it possible to communicate between two ROS systems, exploring in one, and SLAM in the other?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, communication, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I have question about if it possible for one ROS system to do an exploring (Raspberry pi) and transfer data to other ROS system (LINUX) To Use SLAM to draw a map ?
if yes, can someone tells me the main idea or how to start
Thank you

*Because i have seen communication between two ROS system, but i was not sure if is it possible to the extension of using SLAM and RVIZ to have the map on the other machine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280349/is-it-possible-to-communicate-between-two-ros-systems,-exploring-in-one,-and-slam-in-the-other-?/) by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-19**:
What do you mean by

> two ROS systems

? Two computers both running ROS on the same network with the same Master? Something else?

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-19**:
What i mean a Raspberry pi with Jessie OS on it, that runs ROS
but since the Raspberry pi can not handle RVIZ

I will run RVIZ on another computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is "yes." Take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines to see how to set that up.

In practice you'll need to be careful about managing the data flowing over the network. You should run `roscore` and the motor controllers and sensor drivers on the RPi so that your robot is responsive and immune from network hiccups. On the desktop you can run SLAM and exploration; these consume lots of CPU but generate small messages like tf transforms. The challenge is getting the sensor data up to your desktop reliably. Laser data is pretty small, but pointclouds can be huge, so you'll probably need to downsample on the RPi. It really depends on your situation.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0